# Estimating DCC GARCH using a multivariate t-distribution in Matlab

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, matlab, garch, t-distribution

What I want to do is estimate the DCC equation using a multivariate t-distribution, preferably in Matlab. There is a package/toolbox of Sheppard and Shephard. But that one only allows you to use a MVN. Does anyone know how to do this in Matlab (as in do you know of any toolbox which enables the user to use a Multivariate t-distribution for the DCC parameters or do you know how to do this manually in Matlab). Of course, I used Google and it didn't help.

It is strange to observe that we have many applications for the Gaussian distribution, while it is known for quite a time that a normal distribution is not a good fit for most financial returns. The t-distribution is a promising alternative, yet the possibilities (i.e. packages/toolbox/built-in functions) for using one of the promising alternatives seem to be very mediocre.

Comment: Multivariate $t$-distribution for the DCC model is available in "rmgarch" package in R (see the options for the argument `distribution` of the function [`dccspec`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rmgarch/docs/dccspec)). I know nothing about Matlab though.

Comment: Thanks, do you perhaps know if the Q_bar matrix (unconditional correlation matrix of the standardised residuals) is affected by the choice of the distribution used to estimate a DCC-GARCH?

Comment: What I want to do is, estimate the DCC parameters (and the degrees of freedom) with a Multivariate t-distribution, using 'R'. Then, basically just put those estimates in an Excel file and import it in Matlab.

Comment: Yes, I think the $\bar{Q}$ matrix is affected by the choice of the distribution, because essentially everything is affected by that choice.

Comment: I don't have any experience in R, but is it possible, with the use of this package, to extract that $\bar{Q}$  and put it in an Excel file as well (for example by stacking all rows of the matrix so that we get a 1$\times$$N^2$ row where $N$ denotes the number of assets).